# Marketing Cloud: Mobile Push Attributes

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, attribute

I am trying to set some attributes in marketing cloud using the addAtribute method:
(http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/attributes.html)

There it says that it is possible to set any attribute you want:
(Add any attributes you save with the SDK to your Marketing Cloud contact record in advance so that the Marketing Cloud can connect the values sent by the SDK to the correct contact fields.)

The problem is that, using this method, the only fields I am able to set are those from MobilePush Demographics. If I try to set any other attribute, nothing happens. If I set an attribute that does not exist, it is saved within the sdk but it is not created in marketing cloud.

Is it possible to set attributes from any data extension or create new ones using that method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `add` in the SDK's `addAttribute()` is a little misleading.  As the documentation points out, "Add any attributes you save with the SDK to your Marketing Cloud contact record in advance ..."  That step is not optional.  You must log into your Marketing Cloud account and add any custom attributes you wish to "set" (aka "add") from the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, how do you select the data extension from which you want to set the attribute?

Comment: You should reach out to your support manager and open a ticket.  I can only speak for the SDK and have no insight into your (or any) account specific details.

Answer (score 1):

As per Bill's answer, you will need to add attributes in Marketing Cloud. Follow the procedural steps below:

1. Open Contact Builder
2. Click on the MobilePush Data Attribute Group in the constellation view
3. Click on the pencil icon on the 'MobilePush Demographics' Attribute Set
4. Add the required Attributes