# Marketing Cloud PushSDK Attributes not updating

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android, salesforce-sdk-android

I'm implementing the Android PushSDK. I have the following code in my main activity:

```
MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk(sdk -> sdk.getRegistrationManager()
        .edit()
        .setContactKey("123456")
        .setAttribute("First Name", "Hello")
        .setAttribute("Last Name", "World")
        .commit());
```

I looked at [Marketing Cloud: Mobile Push Attributes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150437/marketing-cloud-mobile-push-attributes/155605) already, and I've verified First Name and Last Name are in the Data Designer.

However when I look at the contact, the contact key looks like it came across, but the first name and last name are not filled in:

[image]

Any ideas about this?

Comment: Do you have logging enabled and if so, do you see any logs for the registration request that should be sent once you complete the edit.  Also, you can check the output of MarketingCloudSdk#getSdkState and see when the last registration was successfully sent from your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Attributes can be set with `firstname` and `lastname` without spaces.  This can be seen in the MobilePush Demographics under Audience Builder.  This has always been the case, but I do not know why.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this was the cause!